# Why the image present in the iCarousel view is displayed in the previous screen when I tabbed to previous screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I've implemented a `iCarousel` View, it works properly in its actual screen, but when I tabbed to previous or next screens the image present in the carousel view is appearing on the previous or next screen?

I've used the method `[carouselviewname setHidden:YES]` in `-(void)viewWillDisappear`; but getting the same error.

Here is the link the carousel that has been used:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Please help me!

Here is my code:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [_carouselItems count];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return NUMBER_OF_VISIBLE_ITEMS;//1
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    Category *categoryObj = [_categorymAr objectAtIndex:index];
    //create a numbered view
    NSString *imagePath = [[APP_CACHES_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"catalogues"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.jpg", categoryObj.categoryId]];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IS_IPAD?@"Gallery Placeholder.png":@"Gallery Placeholder.png"]];
    } else {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[APP_CACHES_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"catalogues"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%d.jpg", categoryObj.categoryId]]]];
    }



    if (IS_IPAD) {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 420);
    } else {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    return view;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
    return INCLUDE_PLACEHOLDERS? 2: 0;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;
{
    //create a placeholder view
//  UIView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    label.text = (index == 0)? @"[": @"]";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];

    _spacePageControl.currentPage = index;


//  [view addSubview:label];
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return ITEM_SPACING;
}

- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel

    //set opacity based on distance from camera
    view.alpha = 1.0 - fminf(fmaxf(offset, 0.0), 1.0);

    //do 3d transform
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = _deptCarousel.perspective;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI / 8.0, 0, 1.0, 0);

    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0, 0.0, offset * _deptCarousel.itemWidth);
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //wrap all carousels
//    return NO;
    return wrap;
}

- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index == [self.deptCarousel currentItemIndex]) {
        ProductCategoriesViewController *prodCatView = [[ProductCategoriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD ? 
                                                        @"ProductCategoriesView~iPad" : @"ProductCategoriesView" bundle:nil];
        Category *categoryObj = [_categorymAr objectAtIndex:index];
        [prodCatView setStrTitle:categoryObj.categoryName];
        [prodCatView setCategoryId:categoryObj.categoryId];
        [Flurry logEvent:@"Category List" withParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:categoryObj.categoryName,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",categoryObj.categoryId], nil]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:prodCatView animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Based on your post, my answer would be "because you have a bug in your code." You need to provide a lot more information, and the code to back it up. What is the organization of your screens? Are you using a navigation controller? Tab bar controller? How does the user get from one screen to the next? How is the information about the current item passed from one screen to the next? Do you have iCarousels on both screens? What do you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Sorry I'm using Navigation Controller, by means of it I''m doing navigation. Here is my code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `clipsToBounds` property to `YES` ?

Comment: Have tried it and I'm pleased to say that my error was cleared. Thanks